# Google Translation widget is free or paid function googleTranslateElementInit()

Tags: google-translate

We have found the above mentioned API but we are not sure it requires any user license or agreement with Google.

These API's are free or paid? If paid what is the cost?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
...
function googleTranslateElementInit() {
    new google.translate.TranslateElement({pageLanguage: 'en'}, 'google_translate_element');
}
...
</script>
```

Answer (score -1):

The google cloud translation is not free. You can find more details here. 
https://cloud.google.com/translate/
This Translation API charges on a per-character basis.
You can enquire the cost using the contact sales link provided in the website.

There was a free google translate widget support for websites. Google stopped giving access to the new users. 
You can check their official site for confirmation. https://translate.google.com/intl/en/about/website/ 
They are showing message "We no longer provide new access to Google Translate's Website Translator. This change does not affect existing use of the Website Translator.
We encourage users looking to translate webpages to use browsers that support translation natively."